# Cordova based iOS app gets crashed when call a API which has large response like more that 20MB

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, cordova, indexeddb

Cordova based iOS app gets crashed when calling an API which has a large response like more than 20MB, we are using Vue js and fetching a large book content and saving it in indexedDB and it is working fine for smaller content but if the book content is more than 20-30 MB it gets crashed and the page gets refreshed.

Although this is working fine for android but not in iOS devices.
I am using
"cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",

Comment: Are you still using UIWebView or WKWebView ?

Comment: @Eric I am using WKWebView.

Comment: Do you have any of the crash logs?

Comment: Reducing the Endpoint response size only worked to resolve the issue.